# What does Poison Ivy eat (if anything)?

Tags: dc, poison-ivy

I'm guessing this depends on the version, but I've heard rumors that the Batman villainess Poison Ivy doesn't need to eat. The idea, I think is that she produces chlorophyll for energy, like plants, due to her mutation. There was also the idea that she wouldn't wish to "harm a plant" by eating it.

I could find no confirmation for either, but from what I remember, it *could* fit with the character if she is a human/plant hybrid. Is there any truth to this?

Comment: Extensively discussed here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfcQ0UsY06w - It seems that it depends on who's doing the writing.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks, V. and yes, i know, i have the _Batarang_ question to edit; work has been crazy.

Answer (score 12):

As you said, it depends on the version, but yes, she seems to eat:

- Googling around, you will find pictures of Poison Ivy being served a salad in the main *Batman* animated series;
- I haven't seen the show, but it appears she's depicted as "eating only vegan food" in *Gotham*
- the *Gotham City Sirens* comic had her both doing photosynthesis and eating out "takeout food":

  [image: Poison Ivy and Harley Quinn on a beach]

  [image: Ivy out of the shower, ordering food]
- she's served a salad in *Harley Quinn and Poison Ivy* #1 (2019), though she's not seen eating it.

  [image: Harley and Poison Ivy at a diner]

Comment: In the animated series she eats snails at a restaurant.

Comment: This is what i'm saying; I *know* I've seen her eat before, but it's varied. And considering she is now _confirmed_ metahuman with plant powers, she should be able to absorb and feed off sunlight similar to Superman. Besides, with the way she cares for plants, wouldn;t that be considered a form of _cannibalism?_

Comment: You're welcome to use the example in my (deleted) answer; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/228492/20774